# Who and why is the woman in Tomoe's arms right before he goes on search of Dragon King's eye?

Tags: kamisama-kiss

In *Kamisama Kiss*, who and why is the woman in Tomoe's arms right before he goes on search of Dragon King's eye?

This happens when Nanami first goes in past and sees Tomoe caring for the "beautiful woman".

Is the woman Yukiji? If yes, why does he care for Yukiji as if she is Nanami? Can't he differentiate between the two?

I have only watched the anime and not the manga. Spoilers are fine for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The woman Tomoe was getting the dragon eye was the real Yukiji.

8 years after "Yukiji" (Nanami) promised to marry Tomoe she gave him the hair pin and disappeared, 8 years after that Tomoe met the real Yukiji. She was pregnant, and everyone she knew was murdered, so in order to survive she asked Tomoe to help her, and Tomoe did help her because he thought she was the same "Yukiji" he loved. So he helped her with her pregnancy, and she was keeping her eyes closed, because she knew he could see the difference in her and Nanami's eyes, so she faked being injured.

So because he was helping Yukiji with her pregnancy, he also needed to give her the dragon eye, because her body was weak and pregnant. Even when Nanami one time traveled to the past to get the dragon eye, she saw how Tomoe got it, and Nanami herself helped Yukiji consume it, so Nanami helped a pregnant Yukiji at the time take the dragon eye.

So it was indeed a pregnant Yukiji with Tomoe, and not Nanami. It was all seen and explained in the past manga arc.

Answer (score 1):

As you've said, this happened in the past, 500 or so years before Nanami was even born.  So why should it be odd for him to care for another woman besides Nanami?  It doesn't seem an odd situation to me.

But odd you should ask this question, because the spoiler answer is: Yes, it is Yukiji whom he was carrying for in the past, and actually, no, he can't entirely tell her and Nanami apart. As implied by the fact that the Dragon King's eye was in Nanami's body in the present, Nanami is Yukiji's descendent, and looks quite a bit like her.

But furthermore, further along in the manga, Nanami goes again into Tomoe's past in order to learn about him (for reasons I won't go into here.) After having seen him with Yukiji in the past, she knows that he believed himself in love Yukiji, and so she tries to not interfere with his relationship with Yukiji. It turns out that Yukiji hated youkai, and Nanami ends up saving Tomoe's life when Yukiji refuses. In order to not interfere, Nanami tries to hide herself and tells people to tell Tomoe it was Yukiji that saved him. So, he had in fact fallen in love with Nanami, but due to misdirection, thought it was Yukiji. It's implied on some level he's aware that they are actually different women, as he seems a little confused when they act differently.

Comment: I just wanted to know why he couldn't tell them apart. Thanks though.

Comment: And it has been mentioned many times that Tomoe never loved any woman except Nanami(even though under false name) so I was wondering why he cared for real Yukiji when he was in love with fake Yukiji.

Comment: Ah, right. That's because he lost his memories of being in love with "Yukiji", for reasons. But he kinda sorta loved another woman in that he loved the woman he thought was Yukiji (but was actually Nanami, time traveling, who knew?)

Answer (score 0):

I would say the lady with Tomoe during the period he went to get the dragon eyes was Nanami.

Yukiji has black hair, but the lady with Tomoe had brown hair. Yukiji's hair is always tied down and very long, but right there with Tomoe, her hair was loose and same length as Nanami's, talk about the dragon eyes in her future self, it's easier to explain that it was in her all along from the period Tomoe gave it to her, it all started making sense after she went to the past.

If you remember, the lady with Tomoe had the same condition as Nanami in the past. I wouldn't call it a sickness, it was just a sign for her that it was time to return to her present. Honestly, it's all kinda confusing, but this is what I believe so I wouldn't get more confused.

Comment: and what doesn't even make any sense is the fact that yukiji hates demons, that's includes tomoe, so how the sudden change of heart towards tomoe who thinks its the yukiji he has always known, it has always been nanami from the beginning, time traveling could be confusing and could make sense when you connect the dots properly, we all know the real yukiji finally went to her husband's place during the time she switched places with nanami, tomoe never fell for the real yukiji from the beginning.